# Issue utiling WMIC in bat file when also calling another bat file

Tags: batch-file, cognos, wmic

We are currently in the process of upgrading all our SQL Server 2012 servers to SQL Server 2016. The process involves establishing a new server name and repositioning the alias.

Now, its my job to update all the autosys jobs and bat files to ensure all applications still work. This is the first time I've done this. It's been the practice of previous developers up till now to just hardcode the server name into the bat file. Many of these application trigger Cognos reports as well. Since we want one bat file to handle all environments, so that we can use code deployment, previous developers have used something like the following:

```
REM ************************************************************
REM     Gateway URLs
REM ************************************************************
Set GatewayURL_DEV=Cognos Dev Server
Set GatewayURL_QA=Cognos QA Server
Set GatewayURL_PROD=Cognos_Prod_Server

if '%computername%' == 'VHDDEV' goto Dev
if '%computername%' == 'VHQDPPT' goto QA
if '%computername%' == 'VHPPROD' goto Prod

:Dev
set GateWayURL=%GateWayURL_DEV%
GOTO ExeTrigger

:QA
set GateWayURL=%GateWayURL_QA%
GOTO ExeTrigger

:Prod
set GateWayURL=%GateWayURL_PROD%
GOTO ExeTrigger

:ExeTrigger


E:
cd %TriggerPath%

CALL CognosTrg.bat %GatewayURL% 

exit/B 0
```

Now I don't want to have to change these again with the next upgrade so instead I decided to utilize WMIC to get the domain name. So I came up with the following:

```
REM ************************************************************
REM     Finding the server name
REM ************************************************************
REM 

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%A in ('wmic computersystem get domain /value') do set "Env=%%A"

REM ************************************************************
REM     Branching
REM ************************************************************
if %Env%==dev.company.net (GOTO DEV)
if %Env%==qa.company.net (GOTO QA)
if %Env%==prod.company.net (GOTO PROD)

:DEV
set GateWayURL=%GateWayURL_DEV%
GOTO ExeTrigger

:QA
set GateWayURL=%GateWayURL_QA%
GOTO ExeTrigger

:PROD
set GateWayURL=%GateWayURL_PROD%
GOTO ExeTrigger

:ExeTrigger

echo Host Server Name: %computername%
echo Cognos Environment: %Env%
echo Cognos Gateway: %GateWayURL%
```

This works perfectly and gives me the correct values for all server environments.  The problem comes in when I change the ExeTrigger section to call that Cognos Report.

```
:ExeTrigger

echo Host Server Name: %computername%
echo Cognos Environment: %Env%
echo Cognos Gateway: %GateWayURL%

E:
cd %TriggerPath%

CALL CognosTrg.bat %GatewayURL% 

exit/B 0
```

This fails and the autosys log shows that the assignment doesn't seem to be being made.

```
C:\Users\Act>if ==DEV (GOTO DEV)
```

with the autosys error log showing:

```
(GOTO was unexpected at this time.
```

If I comment out the line CALL CognosTrg.bat %GatewayURL% it runs fine with the autosys log showing:

```
C:\Users\Act>if dev.company.net == dev.company.net (GOTO DEV ) 

C:\Users\Act>set GateWayURL=Cognos Dev Server

C:\Users\Act>GOTO ExeTrigger 

C:\Users\Act>echo Host Server Name: VHDDEV
Host Server Name: VHDDEV

C:\Users\Act>echo Cognos Environment: dev.company.net 
Cognos Environment: dev.company.net

C:\Users\Act>echo Cognos Gateway: Cognos Dev Server
Cognos Gateway: http://"Cognos Dev Server"

C:\Users\Act>E:
E:\>cd "E:\mpapp\Act\Trigger\lib\" 

E:\MPAPP\Act\Trigger\lib>CALL CognosTrg http://"Cognos Dev Server" fired successfully
```

So I can't figure this out. The trigger works on the old server and does execute properly if I just execute the CognosTrg bat file manual. I also decided to just go back and hard code the values and that worked as well.

Is there something wrong with the WMIC execution that fails due to the sub bat file call? I really would like to avoid having to hard code the server names and going back to the "if '%computername%'" practice.

Comment: As a debugging aid, I'd suggest replacing `set "Env=%%A"` with `echo Setting Env to [%%A]& set "Env=%%A"` and see whether the assignment is taking place.

Answer (score 0):

I've a feeling that this may just be an issue with `WMIC`'s strange unicode line ending sequence. If I'm correct you should be able to fix it by changing your for loop to:

```bat
For /F "Skip=1" %%A In ('WMIC ComputerSystem Get Domain') Do For %%B In ("%%A"
) Do Set "Env=%%~B"
```

You may additionally first undefine your variables then check if they're defined after the loop: *(exit script if a value isn't defined)*

```bat
Set "Env="
For /F "Skip=1" %%A In ('WMIC ComputerSystem Get Domain') Do For %%B In ("%%A"
) Do Set "Env=%%~B"
If Not Defined Env Exit/B

Set "GateWayURL="
If "%Env%"=="dev.company.net" Set "GateWayURL=%GateWayURL_DEV%"
If "%Env%"=="qa.company.net" Set "GateWayURL=%GateWayURL_QA%"
If "%Env%"=="prod.company.net" Set "GateWayURL=%GateWayURL_PROD%"
If Not Defined GateWayURL Exit/B

Echo Host Server Name: %ComputerName%
Echo Cognos Environment: %Env%
Echo Cognos Gateway: %GateWayURL%

CD /D "E:\%TriggerPath%"
Call CognosTrg.bat "%GatewayURL%"
```

*The above answers assume your domain name does not include spaces or problematic characters.*

Comment: While the above didn't exactly work, it did provide me enough information to fix the issue. I utilized my existing WMIC statement and then replaced all the GOTO nonsense with the code from Set "GateWayURL=" down. Execution of the autosys job completed successfully and analysis of the autosys log showed all variables to be correctly assigned. Thanks again